# SQL for the following equation. Todays EMA = (Price * (2/11)) + ((1 - (2/11)) * Yesterdays EMA)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-jet-ace

May I ask for your help with the following, please?

I want to create an MS Jet/Ace/Access Query that returns a 10 day Exponential Moving Average (EMA) from a table of price data. The table format and a small set of its data is as follows …

```
TableName = Spot
ID (AutoNumber) aDate (DateTime)        Settle (Double)
1               01/10/2007              16.056
2               02/10/2007              15.625
3               03/10/2007              15.655
4               04/10/2007              15.686
5               05/10/2007              15.810
6               08/10/2007              15.665
7               09/10/2007              15.908
8               10/10/2007              16.004
9               11/10/2007              16.319
10              12/10/2007              16.233
```

In case you are not aware of Exponential Moving Averages, the following websites may help explain them …

http://stockcharts.com/help/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_averages#exponential_moving_a

http://www.pandacash.com/technical-analysis/moving-average/exponential.htm

However, hopefuly I can explain the equation to you.

```
Todays EMA = (Settle * Exponent) + ((1 - Exponent) * Yesterdays EMA)
```

Where

```
Settle = Closing price of the Stock / Asset
Exponent = (2 / (10 Days + 1)) ie 0.1818
```

I have a query that returns some of the values I need, but I am unable to find a solution to the whole thing.

My Query, so far (hopefully the formatting makes it clearer to read)

```
SELECT aDate, Settle, 

   (SELECT((SELECT Settle 
            FROM   SPOT AS SubQ 
            WHERE  SubQ.ID = SS.ID)) 
    FROM   SPOT AS SS 
    WHERE  SS.ID = Spot.ID - 1) AS YesterdaySettle,

   ( 2 / 11 ) AS Exponent,

   (SELECT Settle 
    FROM   SPOT AS SS 
    WHERE  SS.ID = Spot.ID) * ( Exponent ) AS [Part A],

   ( 1 - Exponent ) AS [Part B],

   (SELECT ((SELECT Settle 
              FROM   SPOT AS SubQ 
              WHERE  SubQ.ID = SS.ID) * ( 2 / 11 )) 
    FROM   SPOT AS SS 
    WHERE  SS.ID = Spot.ID - 1) AS [Yesterdays Part A],

   (SELECT SUM(Settle) 
    FROM   SPOT AS SubQ 
    WHERE  ID BETWEEN Spot.ID AND Spot.ID -9) / Iif(Spot.id > 10, 10, Spot.id) AS [10DMA] 

FROM   SPOT
ORDER  BY aDate;
```

Based on the field names of my Query, my equation would be …

```
Todays EMA = ([Part A])  + ([Part B] * [Part C])
```

And I would expect results similar to the following.

```
[10DMA] [Exponent]  [Part A]    [Part B]    [Part C] (Previous EMA)     [EMA]
15.896  0.181818182 2.919272727 0.818181818     USE 10DMA ie 15.896     15.925
15.911  0.181818182 2.840909091 0.818181818                 15.925      15.871
15.945  0.181818182 2.846363636 0.818181818                 15.871      15.831
15.985  0.181818182 2.852       0.818181818                 15.831      15.805
16.027  0.181818182 2.874545455 0.818181818                 15.805      15.806
16.037  0.181818182 2.848181818 0.818181818                 15.806      15.780
16.052  0.181818182 2.892363636 0.818181818                 15.780      15.803
16.054  0.181818182 2.909818182 0.818181818                 15.803      15.840
16.039  0.181818182 2.967090909 0.818181818                 15.840      15.927
16.025  0.181818182 2.951454545 0.818181818                 15.927      15.983
```

The problem is I can’t figure out how to create the [Part C] field.

Some points are …

- If there is no EMA for a day, then the [Part C] value should be
  [10DMA]. For example, the first record will not have a EMA so I need
  to use [10DMA].
- If there is an EMA from yesterday, then use that value for todays [Part C].

May I ask for some advice please. I kind of stumbled across what I have so far, But I am stumped for the Part C value.

I thought I could do something along the lines of …

```
iif (EMA <> 0, EMA, [10DMA]) AS [Part C],
    (([Part A]) + ([Part B] * [Part C])) AS EMA
```

However, I get an error relating to

```
Circular reference caused by alias 'Part C'.
```

Any advice would be gratefully received. Many thanks for your time.

John.

Comment: The circular reference is due to "AS EMA" - can you call it something else, like ABC?

Comment: @ron tornambe. Thank you for responding. The problem is the field EMA doesn't exist. What I mean is, I was trying to create that field with '(([Part A]) + ([Part B] * [Part C])) AS EMA'. Changing the alias to ABC gives me ... 'Parameter EMA has no default value'.